# ReceiveStateAndRefFlow does not receive StatesToRecord parameter

Tags: corda

In Corda, there is a flow which provides the functionality to send **SignedTransaction** to another party.

```
open class SendTransactionFlow(otherSide: FlowSession, stx: SignedTransaction) : DataVendingFlow(otherSide, stx)
```

And another flow, which sends **StatesAndRefs** to another party:

```
open class SendStateAndRefFlow(otherSideSession: FlowSession, stateAndRefs: List<StateAndRef<*>>) : DataVendingFlow(otherSideSession, stateAndRefs)
```

On the acceptor's side corresponding receiver flow should be invoked:

```
open class ReceiveTransactionFlow @JvmOverloads constructor(private val otherSideSession: FlowSession,
                                                            private val checkSufficientSignatures: Boolean = true,
                                                            private val statesToRecord: StatesToRecord = StatesToRecord.NONE) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>()
```

or

```
class ReceiveStateAndRefFlow<out T : ContractState>(private val otherSideSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<@JvmSuppressWildcards List<StateAndRef<T>>>() // which invokes **ReceiveTransactionFlow** with **StatesToRecord.NONE**
```

The key difference between these two acceptor flows is that **ReceiveStateAndRefFlow** will resolve **SignedTransaction** on acceptor's side, but will not record states to the counterparties vault. On the other, hand: **ReceiveTransactionFlow** accepts **StatesToRecord** property and will store states into the counterparty's vault.

**Question**: What is the rationale that **ReceiveStateAndRefFlow** doesn't accept **StatesToRecord** property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no particular reason why `StatesToRecord` cannot be set but there are some tricky edge cases to deal with which may end up in CorDapp developers messing up their vault!

For example: when you force the storing of a single state in the vault the corresponding output in the same transaction will not be stored, resulting you having an unconsumed state in the vault which is actually consumed.

Normally, this wouldn't matter too much because you can't spend it anyway. However, it will result in confusing vault query behaviour.